# Binding image from control page to main page WP7/8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, data-binding

I want bind image from control page to main page but I cannot get it to work. I try this:

```
XAML: <Image Source="{Binding myImage}" Height="150"  Name="photoPreview"...
```

binding:

```
public Image myImage
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Some idea here?

Answer (score 1):

You can't bind an `Image` object to the `Source` property of an Image control. The `Source` property is of type `ImageSource`. Use BitmapImage in your code and bind that instead.

```cs
public BitmapImage myImage { get; set; }
```

Or if the image file is included in your project's assets you can bind the relative path as well (as a string).

Comment: thx for help but it doesnt work. I take photo by camera and then save it to isolated storage. To read from isolate I use this ...
                    bitmap = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(fileStream);
                    photoPreview.Source = bitmap; but image is showing in  control page but i cant bind it to main page.

Comment: How are you setting myImage?

Comment: photoPreview.Source = bitmap; here I load image from isolated storage and show it in conrol page. Now I use public BitmapImage myImage { get; set; } to binding image from control page to main page but unsuccessful

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `Image` type `property` u can `bind` the `image` directly by giving the `path` in `Image` `Source` like this--->

```
<Image Source = "{Binding Path = path}" Height="150"  Name="photoPreview"...
```

where the path (string type) u can set & get

```
public String path
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Comment: thx man nice idea but here is still some problem because image is not binded. If I chceck it via breakpoint path return null. I post more information in answer bellw. Maybe someone get idea where is problem.

Answer (score 0):

More details from my source maybe someone get idea where is problem>

**Control page (POPUP)**

```
 private void SaveToIsolatedStorage(Stream imageStream, string fileName)
    {
        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsoStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (myIsoStorage.FileExists(fileName))
            {
                myIsoStorage.DeleteFile(fileName);
            }

            IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsoStorage.CreateFile(fileName);
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.SetSource(imageStream);

            WriteableBitmap mywb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
            mywb.SaveJpeg(fileStream, mywb.PixelWidth, mywb.PixelHeight, 0, 95);
            fileStream.Close();

        }
        this.ReadFromIsolatedStorage("myImage.jpg");

    }

    private void ReadFromIsolatedStorage(string fileName)
    {
        WriteableBitmap bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(200, 200);
        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsoStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsoStorage.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                bitmap = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(fileStream);
            }
        }

        photoPreview.Source = bitmap;

    }

public String myNote { get; set; }


    public String path
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

**CONTROL PAGE POPUP XAML**

```
 <Image Source = "{Binding Path = path}" Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Name="photoPreview"
```

**New class for binding named Note.cs**

> public class Note : INotifyPropertyChanged
>       {

```
    public String myNote { get; set; }

    public String path
    {
        get;
        set;
    }...
```

**Main page**

```
  var note = new Note();
            note.myNote = control.myNote;
            note.OnPropertyChanged("myNote");
            note.path = control.path;
            note.OnPropertyChanged("path");
            Notes.Add(note);
            OnPropertyChanged("Notes");
```

**Main page. xaml**

```
  <Image Width="100" Height="100" Stretch="Fill" Source = "{Binding Path = path}"></Image>
```

P.s binding text myNote from textbox work great but image not.